# Calculating grades

Tags: python

I am working on a program to calculate various set

```
# Evan Gertis
# 09/15/2022
# frequency_distribution.py
import numpy as np

nums = [[68,84,75,82,68,90,62,88,76,93],[73, 79, 88, 73, 60, 93, 71, 59, 85, 75],[61,65,75, 87,74, 62, 95, 78, 63, 72],[66,78,82,75,94,77,69,74,68,60],[96,78,89,61,75,95,60,79,83,71],[79,62,67,97,78,85,76,65,71,75],[65,80,73,57,88,78,62,76,53,74],[86,67,73,81,72,63,76,75,85,77]]

max = max(nums)[0]
min = min(nums)[0]
print("The highest grade is:")
print(max)
print("The lowest grade is:")
print(min)
print("The range is:")
print(max - min)
```

The next set of calculations that I would like to determine is

1. The 5 highest elements
2. The 5 lowest elements

Comment: Side note, don't use `min`/`max` as variable names. `max = max(nums)[0]` will cause issues ;)

Comment: what are "nums"? is it like `grades = [person1grades, person2grades]` ? getting `max()` of a list containing lists is probably not what you want

Comment: Use `heapq.nlargest` https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest

Comment: See `heapq.nlargest` and `heapq.nsmallest` at the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Just as one example, `min(nums)[0]` is 61, but the lowest value across all lists is actually 53. What are you trying to do here?